# adding x-axis labels to mpandroid bar chart shows only the first label in the array list

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I would like to add x-axis labels to my bar chart all I get is the first label only being shown
[image: The current out put]

The code that I am using is as follows. I have customized it from the demo data provided in the documentation of the library that I am using mpandroidchart

```
      public class HomeFragment extends SimpleFragment implements OnChartGestureListener {

@NonNull
public static Fragment newInstance() {
    return new HomeFragment();
}

private BarChart chart;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    BarChart chart = (BarChart) v.findViewById(R.id.chart);
    BarData data = new BarData(getDataSet());
    data.setBarWidth(10f);
    chart.setData(data);
    chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
    chart.invalidate();
    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(getXAxisValues()));

    return v;
}

private ArrayList getDataSet() {
    ArrayList dataSets = null;
    ArrayList valueSet1 = new ArrayList();
    BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(0.f, 0); // Jan
    valueSet1.add(v1e1);
    BarEntry v1e2 = new BarEntry(20.000f, 2); // Feb
    valueSet1.add(v1e2);
    BarEntry v1e3 = new BarEntry(40.000f, 4); // Mar
    valueSet1.add(v1e3);
    BarEntry v1e4 = new BarEntry(60.000f, 6); // Apr
    valueSet1.add(v1e4);
    BarEntry v1e5 = new BarEntry(80.000f, 8); // May
    valueSet1.add(v1e5);
    BarEntry v1e6 = new BarEntry(100.000f, 10); // Jun
    valueSet1.add(v1e6);
    BarEntry v1e7 = new BarEntry(120.000f, 12); // Jan
    valueSet1.add(v1e7);
    BarEntry v1e8 = new BarEntry(140.000f, 14); // Feb
    valueSet1.add(v1e8);
    BarEntry v1e9 = new BarEntry(160.000f, 16); // Mar
    valueSet1.add(v1e9);
    BarEntry v1e10 = new BarEntry(180.000f, 18); // Apr
    valueSet1.add(v1e10);
    BarEntry v1e11 = new BarEntry(200.000f, 20); // May
    valueSet1.add(v1e11);
    BarEntry v1e12 = new BarEntry(220.000f, 22); // Jun
    valueSet1.add(v1e12);
    BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "Monthly Sales");
    barDataSet1.setColors(ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS);
    dataSets = new ArrayList();
    dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
    return dataSets;
}

private ArrayList getXAxisValues() {
    ArrayList xAxis = new ArrayList();
    xAxis.add("JAN");
    xAxis.add("FEB");
    xAxis.add("MAR");
    xAxis.add("APR");
    xAxis.add("MAY");
    xAxis.add("JUN");
    xAxis.add("JULY");
    xAxis.add("AUG");
    xAxis.add("SEPT");
    xAxis.add("OCT");
    xAxis.add("NOV");
    xAxis.add("DEC");
    return xAxis;
    }
}
```

I am new to this library hence probably I am doing some mistakes, I am using this sample as it will be easy to customize it further to get data from the database. What could I be doing wrong?

I have tried this line  `xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(getXAxisValues()));` in a loop as follows

```
    for(int i=0; i<=12;i++){
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(getXAxisValues().subList(0,i)));
    }
```

That too is just displaying the first label only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need following code:

```
for(int i=0; i<=12;i++){
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(getXAxisValues().subList(0,i)));
}
```

All you need is to replace above code with this line:

```
chart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(getXAxisLables()));
```

And the method to get labels is:

```
private ArrayList<String> getXAxisLabels()
{
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String> ();

    labels.add( "JAN");
    labels.add( "FEB");
    labels.add( "MAR");
    labels.add( "APR");
    labels.add( "MAY");
    labels.add( "JUN");
    return labels;
}
```

Please modify the getLabels() method in accordance to your requirements.

Comment: Let me know if you need further assistance. Happy coding!